# Who's Online From Users in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Good evening! How to find out who's online from users? I need this information at admin panel.
I used materials from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html to work with Users table.

```
securuty.yml
 providers:
  main:
   entity: { class: Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lastLogin property. The most basic functionality is to use the field and suppose that all users who logged in last X minutes are online.

Another possibility is to add a logging system based on a listener that updates the user status in a DB on every page change. Then again, you query all users with an activity logged in last few minutes.

The most efficient system would be a sort of a javascript listener that would update the user online in an AJAX query after a page load - making an asynchronous query would assure that there is no overhead.